# Angular creating component with CLI gives encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

Learning angular5. When I use CLI of Angular to create new components I get the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 
}
```

However `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` makes the code break and put out the following error message:

[image]

I know how to fix the bug just by removing `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. Is there however a way to not have this line of code in the first place?

Comment: Are you importing `ViewEncapsulation` from `@angular/core`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add import

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

but you have to know that ViewEncapsulation.Emulated is the default one, it's better to use emulated. ViewEncapsulation.Native will not work on all browsers

Comment: This does not answer the question. @delasteve's answer does.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently an outstanding issue that the CLI is generating `ViewEncapsulation.None`. This is being tracked here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8398

There is a PR to fix this bug as well, tracked here: https://github.com/angular/devkit/pull/270

For now, you have two options.

1. You can delete the line `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to get rid of the error. Angular will default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`.
2. You can keep that line and do as Fateh mentions and add the import. This would keep the `ViewEncapsulation` set to `None` which could lead to other issues, such as styles being applied on components you don't want them to be applied to.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular CLI Version 1.5.3**

```
ng g component test
```

This version of angular cli generates following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This means the encapsulation mode is by default [ViewEncapsulation.Emulated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).